# BS4 + Python3: unable to crawl tree: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'has_attr'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python (I only know powershell) and I'm trying to learn Web Crawling with BS4+Python3.

Here's a simple exercise i was practicing with:

```
<h1 class="entry-title">
<a href="test1.html">test1</a></h1>
<h1 class="entry-title">
<a href="test2.html" rel="bookmark">test2</a></h1>
```

What I want to do is get ONLY  details (href and .string) with attributes "rel"

Heres my code

```
for h1_Tag in soup.find_all(("h1", { "class" : "entry-title" })):
    for a_Tag in h1_Tag.contents:
        if a_Tag.has_attr('rel'):
           print (a_Tag)
```

but i'm getting:
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'has_attr'

What am I doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over all the contents, including `NavigableString` objects; e.g. text.

If you wanted to find all elements with a `rel` attribute, search for them instead:

```
for h1_Tag in soup.find_all(("h1", { "class" : "entry-title" })):
    for a_Tag in h1_Tag.find_all('a', rel=True):
       print(a_Tag)
```

The `rel=True` keyword argument constrains the search to elements that have that attribute; `<a>` tags with no `rel` attribute will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `SoupStrainer`. This will allow you to parse the document based on pre-defined conditions. Using Python 2.7 and BeautifulSoup 4.3.2, so the logic is similar.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup, SoupStrainer as strain

ofile = open("test.html")
strain = strain(rel=True)
soup = bsoup(ofile, parse_only=strain)

print soup
```

Result:

```
<a href="test2.html" rel="bookmark">test2</a>
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Let us know if this helps.